# What type of France visa should I get?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, france

I am a PhD student from India. I plan to visit France to attend an event, to be held during xxth - xxth May 2017, (8 days), La Colle sur Loup, France. I have been selected and I will attend the event to present my poster. I am not presenting a a paper, but just a poster. This is a lecture course. For such a case, what should be my visa type, will it be Student visa or Scientist visa, or anything else. Can someone please give me some info?

I have the acceptance letter for my abstract telling me that I am selected for the poster presentation and that they look forward to see me there...

Comment: Are you taking a course at a university or are you attending an academic conference? It sounds like a conference, but you say it's a "lecture course."

Comment: @ZachLipton He's most likely doing a presentation at a university for students at that uni

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: @JoErNanO Indian

Answer (score 2):

Different embassies have different application forms, but [**this one**](http://www.vfs-france.co.in/PDF/Visa_Form_France_Schengen_Revised_040214.pdf) is good for use at any French embassy.

In it, select "Business".

It is strongly recommended for you to get a letter of invitation from the university you're visiting. Ask them to send you a formal invitation explaining exactly what you will be doing in France, and how long you will be staying there.

Ask them to fax a copy to the French embassy where you're applying, and present it together with your flight booking confirmation, hotel booking and bank statement proving you have enough money to support yourself while in France

Comment: I have the acceptance letter for my abstract telling me that I am selected for the poster presentation and that they look forward to see me there....